# Pagination in laravel inserts a new row in the database

Tags: php, database, laravel, pagination, insert

I've got an issue when I do pagination with Laravel.

This is the method in my Controller:

```
public function manageElection(Request $r,$id,$idx){
    $program = MProgram::find($idx);

    $person = MPeople::find($id);

    $treatment = Treatment::where('people_id',$person->id)->first();

    if($treatment!=null){
        $treatment->relation($program->id);// se supone que esto lo pone en la tabla N-N
    }else{
        $treatment = new Treatment();
        $treatment->people_id = $id;
        $treatment->user_id = 1; //Cuando este la autentificación acabada, esto habrá que cambiarlo
        $treatment->center_id = 1; //ESTO HAY QUE CAMBIARLO
        $treatment->saveTreatment();
        $treatment->relation($program->id);// se supone que esto lo pone en la tabla N-N
    }

    $mgobjectives = Mgobjective::all();
```

$msobjectives = Msobjective::paginate(7);

```
return view('addPeopleProgram')->with('gobjectives',$mgobjectives)->with('sobjectives',$msobjectives)->with('program',$program)->with('treatment',$treatment);
```

}

This is the route:

```
Route::any('/electionProgram/{id}-{idx}','MpeopleController@manageElection');
```

And this is the view:

```
@extends('layouts.app') 
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
           <a href="/elementos">Atrás</a>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="/addPeopleObjective  /{{$program->id}}" >
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Añade objetivos generales a este programa</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        @foreach($gobjectives as $gobjective)
                            <li>
                                <label>{{$gobjective->name}}</label>
                                <div class="checkbox"> 
                                    <label><input value="{{$gobjective->id}}" type="radio" name="gobjectives{{$gobjective->id}}" class="subject-list">Si</label>
                                    <!--<label><input value="no" type="radio" name="{{$gobjective->name}}{{$gobjective->id}}" class="subject-list">No</label>-->
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>Añadir objetivos específicos a este programa</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        @foreach($sobjectives as $sobjective)
                            <li>
                                <label>{{$sobjective->name}}</label>
                                <div class="checkbox"> 
                                    <label><input value="{{$sobjective->id}}" type="radio" name="sobjectives{{$sobjective->id}}" class="subject-list">Si</label>
                                    <!---<label><input value="noS" type="radio" name="{{$sobjective->name}}{{$sobjective->id}}" class="subject-list">No</label>-->
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {{ $sobjectives->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Terminar"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

@endsection

Pagination works, the problem is when I select the page 2, Laravel tries to save (again) the object Treatment and the relation that it haves with program

```
$treatment->saveTreatment();
$treatment->relation($program->id);
```

Relation is a method in the model Treatment:

```
public function relation($id){
    $this->programs()->attach($id);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea that what can be happening? I've been loking but I didn't have cases like mine. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The error that I have is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7-1' for key 'mprogram_treatment_mprogram_id_treatment_id_unique'
```

Comment: as @Christophvh said, your code must have a function to store data,  another for get data, for delete and so on. I don't know where you learnt or who teached you Laravel but there're easier and better ways to do that (If you use Doctrine repositories they have a paginator tool for example)

Comment: Your insert query for treatment is in the same controller for each pages. So whenever you switch the page it will be execute. You have to Block it with proper if condition.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have to seperate the store from when I want to show something, but the reason that I put it together is because after saving in the db the treatment, I what to show the view that I have above in the other method I if I doesn't do it together it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to seperate your routes. You are getting the data and posting the data in the same controller method. So every time you try to retreive your data you are posting a new record in the database.

Below is an example: (this is no working code probably, but it is to illustrate a point).

To store your data:

```
public function storeElection(Request $r,$id,$idx){
    $program = MProgram::find($idx);

    $person = MPeople::find($id);

    $treatment = Treatment::where('people_id',$person->id)->first();
    $treatment->relation($program->id);

    if($treatment->isEmpty()){
        $treatment = new Treatment();
        $treatment->people_id = $id;
        $treatment->user_id = 1; //Cuando este la autentificación acabada, esto habrá que cambiarlo
        $treatment->center_id = 1; //ESTO HAY QUE CAMBIARLO
        $treatment->saveTreatment();
        $treatment->relation($program->id);// se supone que esto lo pone en la tabla N-N
    }

    // Return here to a view where you can see your data
```

Your controller where you want to show your data:

```
public function showObjectives()
{

$mgobjectives = Mgobjective::all();
$msobjectives = Msobjective::paginate(7);

return view('addPeopleProgram', compact('mgobjectives','msobjectives');

}
```

Separate routes

Example route to store your data:

```
Route::post('/electionProgram/{id}-{idx}','MpeopleController@storeElection');
```

Example route to get your data and paginate it

```
Route::get('/electionObjectives', 'MpeopeleController@showObjectives')
```

Ps:

- I have made a answer related to your code. But this code is not
  really RESTfull. Please take a look at this :
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers . It
  will structure your code much better.

  - Judging from the naming of your controllers you are doing too much inside a single controller. For example: you will probably need a PeopleController / TreatmentController / ObjectiveController to seperate your logic. (this is just a assumption because i don't know what you are building.)

Comment: The problem that I have if I doe that is in the store election, I want to view the same thing that in showElections, the view  addPeopleProgram with the same objects, because I have to show the type of objectives there are to also relate them with the treatment created, and if I don't do it like in my comment above I don't now how. I done what you say to me but now I have this problem.

Comment: I also have the Objective controller TreatmentController y PeopleController, but I don't know how to call a method of one controller from another controller.

Comment: Controllers aje just simple Classes. So just study how to work with OOP.

Comment: What I've seen in other pages about calling methods of controllers between them isn't like normal classes.

Comment: The questions that you are asking in these comments show that you indeed don't understand the basics of MVC and OOP , and i can't really explain them in my answer. The only tip i can give you is to watch this free course to get a better understanding: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017.

Comment: You can move $treatment->relation($program->id); before if statement. :)

Comment: @PatrykWoziński yeah i know, there is a lot of refactoring that can be done, but like i said i just wanted to illustrate a point :)

Comment: Ye, I know. it's just a suggestion.